# Combining separate body and facial motion capture

Tags: animation, rigging, motion-capture

Hoping someone can help with this, i have a human generator rig which has a rigify - meta human rig for both body and face. I have a FBX Mocap file for the body and a TXT and WAV file for the face using Facecap.

I have been using Autorig Pro to retarget bones of the body rig and separately this works well, i also then have to create the shapekeys for the face in Faceit and this normally works on its own fine.

My issue is that the Human Generator comes in one piece so i have tried separating the head to do the duplicate workaround but it doesn't transfer over at the end and the duplicate leaves the body, plus when i add the body they don't work together.
we are new to animation and are struggling with this, we have even thought about iclone 7 but i want to know if there is a workaround in blender and what the process is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. You have to parent all the bones of the face rig to the head bone of the auto rig. That is if you want the face rig. But the shapekeys for the face should be animated separately because there are no bones involved there. Just copy/paste the keys to the body mesh in the timeline (be sure to keyframe on frame 1 at first so the f-curve is present).